# Cannot get the new table's FK-constraints in an AFTER ALTER trigger

Tags: oracle, plsql

I'm trying to create a trigger for `AFTER ALTER` event on schema's tables which would work with the new FK-constraints, here's my test code:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER Test_Trigger
AFTER ALTER ON SCHEMA
WHEN (ORA_DICT_OBJ_TYPE = 'TABLE')
DECLARE
  TYPE queryRows IS TABLE OF USER_CONSTRAINTS%ROWTYPE;
  resultRows queryRows := queryRows();
BEGIN
  -- Get all the FK-constraints for the ALTERed table
  SELECT *
  BULK COLLECT INTO resultRows
  FROM USER_CONSTRAINTS
  WHERE Constraint_Type = 'R'
    AND Table_Name = ORA_DICT_OBJ_NAME;

  -- Output all the found constraints
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Here are '|| resultRows.COUNT ||' constraints:');
  FOR i IN 1..resultRows.COUNT LOOP
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(
        'FK-costraint: '|| resultRows(i).Constraint_Name
      ||' on table '|| resultRows(i).Table_Name
    );
  END LOOP;
END;
/

-- Creating some table
CREATE TABLE People (
   ID        NUMBER(6)    PRIMARY KEY
 , Name      VARCHAR2(31)
 , Parent_ID NUMBER(6)
);

-- Altering the table and adding an FK constraint,
-- the trigger fires here but can't find any new constraints
ALTER TABLE People ADD CONSTRAINT FK_People_People_Parent_ID_ID
                   FOREIGN KEY (Parent_ID) REFERENCES People (ID);
```

And the output is:

```
Here are 0 constraints:
```

In other words, the trigger can't find any new constraints, but there is a new constraint:

```
SELECT Table_Name, Constraint_Name
FROM USER_CONSTRAINTS
WHERE Constraint_Type = 'R'
  AND Table_Name = 'PEOPLE';
```

gives this row:

```
.--------------------------------------------.
| TABLE_NAME | CONSTRAINT_NAME               |
|------------|-------------------------------|
| PEOPLE     | FK_PEOPLE_PEOPLE_PARENT_ID_ID |
'--------------------------------------------'
```

Although when I tried the same code on `AFTER CREATE` instead of `AFTER ALTER` it worked with creating tables for some reason (the FK-constraints were found).